# How to forbid javascript execution?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I got a site with an some block where is AJAX-loaded code coming from remote server. How can I forbid to execute code, that may come from remote server? Is "noscript" tag really enough?

I think we should not take in attention cases in which `</noscript><script>...</script>` is coming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It all depends on what you do with the data you load. Show what you are doing with it

Comment: @Pekka웃 Just embed it in some "div" block.

Comment: How are you embedding it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Another script loads that code through AJAX-request.

Comment: Why not show the actual code so somebody can actually tell you whether you have something to worry about or not?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Because actually there is no code at the moment. I'm in stage of thinking :)

Comment: It will depend on what code you use. jQuery's `.html()` will parse script blocks. Native `.innerHTML` will not.

Comment: @Pekka웃 What will jQuery's .html() do with script blocks?

Comment: As said, will parse them, leading to their execution.

Comment: sounds a bit like an iframe you have there. What if you write some code to strip out any script/javascript tags from the remote content?

Comment: @uv_man The best solution at the moment from supposed.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I forbid to execute code, that may come from remote server?

Make the Ajax request to your own server. Request the data from the remote server from yours. Run it through an HTML parser and a whitelist (an XSS filter). Then return it to the client.

> Is "noscript" tag really enough?

`noscript` provides content that browsers are expected to ignore if the *browser* doesn't support JS. It doesn't provide any kind of sandboxing.

Comment: Isn't it much easier to just not do anything with the data received that might execute any scripts in it?

Comment: @Quentin The idea is to make a SaaS service that should provide such code blocks. So now I stuck how can I guarantee (even partly) to potential clients so there is no any viruses or XSS attacks through transmitted blocks.

Comment: @kseen then Quentin's answer is what you need. `Run it through an HTML parser and a whitelist (an XSS filter).` It's not completely trivial

Comment: @kseen so you want to be able to download JS code to executive at the client, but at the same time you don't want to executive code? Please tell how you would like to do that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just want to download some identificator with an layout. Like `<p style="color: red">ATT10123</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You could target that specific element (using a selector) you want to load via ajax load. So for example (hope this isn't confusing but here goes):

http://jsbin.com/efazun/2 - (Page 1) Has an alert which displays 'hello world' when page is loaded.

http://jsbin.com/ezewep/4/edit (Page 2) - uses jquery load to load **Page 1**, which displays hello world (executing the script when loaded - not good)

http://jsbin.com/ezewep/2/edit (Page 3) - uses jquery load to load **Page 1**, but target the text only, not executing any script (no hello world message).

For more info: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think using of jQuery isn't efficient for my task (as I want to make an SaaS service). I just need native, 'raw' code that will work with any brpwser and cut any execution of js. SOmething like that.